# how to take user input in html and set it as a variable in js?

Tags: javascript, html

How would I take user input from html and set it to a variable in javascript?

This is what i'm trying to implement:

```
<p>
    <label>how old are you?</label>
     <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <input   style=position:absolute;top:80%;left:5%;width:40%; type="number" id="userInput">
      <input    style=position:absolute;top:50%;left:5%;width:40%; type="submit"    onclick="age()">
     </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function age()
      {
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
        alert(input);
      }
      if(age<20)
      {
      alert(YOU ARE UNDER 20)
      }
    </script>
    </p>
```

Comment: use double quotes in your `alert` if your printing a string eg : `alert("YOU ARE UNDER 20")`

Comment: @T. Ou you are save the input value in variable input but you check with if(age<20).so you have to change if(input<20).also you have to print sting use double queotes. alert("YOU ARE UNDER 20")

Comment: @T. Ou also you saved input to the variable not the value. So you have to use below code document.getElementById("userInput").value;

Answer (score 2):

With pure JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
alert(input.value);
```

With jQuery:

```
var input = $('#userInput');
alert(input.val());
```

To achieve what you want:

```
function age() {
  var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
  var age = parseInt(input.value);

  if(age < 20) {
    alert('YOU ARE UNDER 20');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code. I will explain them.
1. You are creating a `var input = document.getElementById("userInput");` But after that in your `alert(input)` it returns the entire object instead of the input value. 2. After that you are comparing Age wich is undefined because you didnt created `var age = input;`. If you compare input<20 it will work. In your alert you didnt use double quotes("") to create a string and alert that string. I hope its more clear now.

```js
     function age()
      {
        var age = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        alert(age);
      
      if(age<20) { alert("YOU ARE UNDER 20"); }
      }
```

```html
<p>
    <label>how old are you?</label>
     <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <input   style=position:absolute;top:80%;left:5%;width:40%; type="number" id="userInput">
      <input    style=position:absolute;top:50%;left:5%;width:40%; type="submit"    onclick="age()">
     </form>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [document.getelementbyId](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0r5fa5KPVAhXGo5QKHfWuAIEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_document_getelementbyid.asp&usg=AFQjCNHDOoJUQbBS14kLimCKYChZUvSqgg)

or

[document.getelementbyclassname](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

`alert(document.getElementById("userinput"));`

or

`alert( document.getElementsByClassName("classname"));`

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```js
function age()
      {
        var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;      
      if(input<20) { alert("YOU ARE UNDER 20"); }
      }
```

```html
<p>
    <label>how old are you?</label>
     <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <input type="number" id="userInput">
      <input    style=position:absolute;top:50%;left:5%;width:40%; type="submit"    onclick="age()">
     </form>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to achieve?
if you want to check age then move if inside function

```
  function age()
  {
    var age = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    if(age<20)
    {
      alert("YOU ARE UNDER 20")
    }
  }
```